# Displaying several binary images in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binary

I was trying to display several images in asp.net mvc. my problem is, they're not loading parallel.

Im calling the images like this:

```
<img alt=""  src="/Picture/Image/?picid=@pic.ImageId">
```

and the method which displays the images is:

```
public ActionResult Image(string picid)
    {
        var pictureid = new Guid(picid);
        var picture = _mediaRepository.GetImageById(pictureid);

        return File(picture.ImageData, picture.MimeType);
     }
```

but as i already said, the images are not loading parallel this way, that means, the browser can only draw one picture at the time, this causes very long latency, when im trying to display 10 images (e.g. in a grid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have session state enabled in your controller (it is by default), then it will only serve one request at once to a single session.  If your GetImageById is taking a long time, then requests will potentially be noticeably delayed.

You should try adding `[SessionState(SessionStateBehaviour.Disabled)]` or `[SessionState(SessionStateBehaviour.ReadOnly)]` to your controller class, though you do need to understand what they're doing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute(v=vs.118).aspx